# using same session variable across my pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

Another question guys.

Regarding session variables. 
I've got an input field (as seen from one of my previous questions ) 
I'll put some code here so you guys can see

```
   function getBaseUrl() {
                return "@Url.Content("~/paging")";
            }

            function LocationSearch(baseUrl) {
                 window.location = getBaseUrl() + "/LocationSearch?searchstring=" + (document.getElementById('vestigingen').value);
            }
```

that is my javascript function calling my controller function.

```
  <input type="text" class="search-query span3" id="vestigingen">
                  <a class="zoekbtn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="LocationSearch();">zoeken</a>
```

Those two are used to pass my search string to my controller.

This is my function in my Paging controller

```
   public ActionResult LocationSearch(int? page, string searchstring)
    {
        if (searchstring != null)
        {
            Session["location"] = searchstring;
        }
        var searchVestigingen = ziekenhuisRepository.GetZiekenhuisList();  //sloppy! get rid of implicity 
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        try
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(Session["location"].ToString(), 0))
            {
                searchVestigingen = ziekenhuisRepository.FindZipcodeVestigingen(Session["location"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                searchVestigingen = ziekenhuisRepository.FindLocationVestigingen(Session["location"].ToString());
            }
            if (searchVestigingen.Count() <= 0)
            {
                return View("NoResults");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("NoResults");                
        }

        return View(searchVestigingen.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, DefaultPageSize));
    }





 public ActionResult ListSearch(int? page, string searchstring)
    {
        if (searchstring != null)
        {
            Session["location"] = searchstring;
        }
      do stuff
     return View(etc. etc. )
    }
```

As you can see I'm using the session variable to go through my pagedlist ( I used MvcPaging package ).

There are two functions where I want to use the same session variable.

- LocationSearch: someone wants to find something inserts the location presses the submit button and result are being shown.
- ListSearch  the same person wants to find something else but does not want insert the same location again.

Here is my question , how can I get the same value that he just inserted to be used in my other function ( and vice versa if he pressed the other button first)?

Comment: Nothing should change regarding your Session, it's designed to be used by multiple pages.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but let's say I type in Los Angeles it does what it should do , paging works , how can I get the same session variable in my other function. Should I take a reference of some sort to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Session object is like a global reference for a specific user and session. Use it however you want and just call `Session["location"]` from anywhere in your project. Have you tried it and it doesn't work or are you just uncertain about the security?

You might need to call it like this though:

```
var location = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["location"].ToString();
```

It might also be good to know that the session variable will be empty if the user closes the browser. That is unless you save it at the client or in a database of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Session, by design, is available to your entire application. You access it the same way regardless of what page you are on.

So you can set a value in one class or method:

```
Session["location"] = searchstring;
```

And then access it from another class or method:

```
searchstring = (string)Session["location"];
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for more information.